# ABS does not stick AFTER some good layers

Tags: heated-bed, adhesion, abs, rafts, dremel-3d45

Usually I had problems with the adhesion of the first layers, and most questions here and out there are about this issue.

Instead now I'm facing another problem. After "some" (few or even after 10h) suddenly the filament does not stick anymore to the previous layers.

Here an example:

[image]

As you can see it completed the rafting very good (not sure if there also some few layer of the object) but then the new layer did not adhere and I had to stop the printing.

Some useful information:

- machine: Dremel 3D45
- filament type: Geeetech ABS
- slicer: Cura
- bed temperature: 100 °C
- nozzle temperature: 240 °C
- layer thickness: 0.2 mm
- cooling: OFF
- printing speed: 30-60 mm/s (lower value is for top/bottom/walls)
- rafting: 0.36 mm base + 1 middle layer + 2 top layer + 0.3 mm air gap
- supports: ON

What can be the reason for such a failure?

### UPDATE

I had better results (not perfect, though) increasing the temperature to 245 °C and reducing the air gap between raft and object to 0.1 mm.

Comment: The air gap is quite large! It is printing in the air with too less material. Furthermore it looks as if the print doesn't have supports as the filament sags on certain areas. Please add, by [edit] if there is support used. You could consider ditching the raft completely, this is an enclosed printer, you could preheat the chamber using the heated bed and use a large brim.

Comment: Is it in an enclosure?  Maybe the higher levels are cooling too much.

Comment: @Oscar question edited. I used supports and the air gap was the default one. Reducing it led to a better adhesion. And yes, the chamber was already pre-heated. I cannot use larger brim/raft because I'm at the limit of the build surface.

Comment: @DaveX yes, the Dremel 3D45 is enclosed.